# Performing operation on each column

Tags: python

How can a loop be used to iterate through columns, applying the same function to each column in a pandas dataframe?

For example, the following code normalizes the 'Cat1' Column.

```
s['Cat1'] = (s.Cat1-s.Cat1.min())/(s.Cat1.max()-s.Cat1.min())
```

How can this code be extended so that the normalization is applied to Cat1...Cat50?

Comment: Pythonic way to do this is using map() and lambda, or using comprehension. Hard to give working example without knowing what data structure "s" is. s['Cat1'] means this is dictionary, but s.Cat1 means this is object...

Comment: "s" is a pandas dataframe containing numerical data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming s is a dictionary, the term s.Cat1 doesn't make any sense.

If s is a class, then now s['Cat1'] doesn't make any sense because class has no attribute **__getitem__**

So I am not sure what s is in your example... But if you want an easy way to generate the strings 'Cat1',...,'Cat50', you can use:

```
for i in range(1,51):
    name = 'Cat%s' % i
    # s[name] = ...
```